# Create text file of hexadecimal from binary

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, binary, hex

I would like to convert a binary to hexadecimal in a certain format and save it as a text file.

The end product should be something like this:

```
"\x7f\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xd2\x64\x8b\x52"
```

Input is from an executable file "a".
This is my current code:

```
with open('a', 'rb') as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    hexbyte = '\\x%02s' % byte
    print hexbyte
```

A few issues with this:

1. This only prints the first byte.
2. The result is "\x" and a box like this:

`00
7f`

In terminal it looks exactly like this:
[image]

Why is this so? And finally, how do I save all the hexadecimals to a text file to get the end product shown above?

EDIT: Able to save the file as text with

```
txt = open('out.txt', 'w')
print >> txt, hexbyte
txt.close()
```

Comment: You are confusing a hexadecimal and binary representation of the data. Your 'end product' is not hexadecimal, it's the binary. Show us the input data please.

Comment: And you only ever read 1 byte of the data, because you say `byte = f.read(1)` and you have no loop or other method to read more data. I don't know what the `\\\\` is supposed to do.

Comment: If you want to convert the byte to hex: `"0x%02X" % ord(byte)` or `"0x{:02}".format(ord(byte))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject numbers into escape sequences like that. Escape sequences are essentially constants, so, they can't have dynamic parts.

There's already a module for this, anyway:

```
from binascii import hexlify
with open('test', 'rb') as f:
  print(hexlify(f.read()).decode('utf-8'))
```

Just use the hexlify function on a byte string and it'll give you a hex byte string. You need the `decode` to convert it back into an ordinary string.

Not quite sure if `decode` works in Python 2, but you really should be using Python 3, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, it does not give me "/x" in front of every 2 characters. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks like a representation of a bytestring in Python returned by `repr()`:

```
with open('input_file', 'rb') as file:
    print repr(file.read())
```

Note: some bytes are shown as ascii characters e.g. `'\x52' == 'R'`. If you want all bytes to be shown as the hex escapes:

```
with open('input_file', 'rb') as file:
    print "\\x" + "\\x".join([c.encode('hex') for c in file.read()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the content to `list` and `print`:

```
with open("default.png",'rb') as file_png:
    a = file_png.read()

l = []
l.append(a)
print l
```